# Misunderstanding with move constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, move

I have such class, where I create a `move constructor`

```
class Test
{
private:
    int m_a;

public:
    Test(int val) { m_a = val; }

    Test (const Test &) {}
    
    // move constructor
    Test (Test && d)
    {
        std::cout << &m_a << std::endl;   // Line X
        std::cout << &d.m_a << std::endl;
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << m_a << std::endl;
    }
};
```

I also create a function to test `move constructor`

```
void fun(Test a)
{ return ; }
```

Than in `main` function I create 2 objects of class above and call function to test `move constructor`

```
int main()
{
    Test a {50};
    Test b {100};

    fun(a);
    fun(std::move(a));

    fun(b);
    fun(std::move(b));

    return 0;
}
```

When I looked at the output, I was surprised, because the address of o `m_a` variable in `line X` has same address for both objects.

```
0x7ffc40d37bb4   // look at this
0x7ffc40d37bac
0x7ffc40d37bb4   // look at this
0x7ffc40d37bb0
```

How is it possible ? It's not static member, what is going on ? Compiler optimization or what ?

Comment: did you mean to do `fun(Test(std::move(a)));` ?

Comment: The argument is a copy and happens to be stored in the same place in both calls. Print `&a.m_a` and `&b.m_a` in `main`and compare all of them.

Comment: @Abel what is the difference  ?

Comment: It might just make an extra copy via move constructor.  Fun passes a Test by value so unless it got optimized out, it may literally mean copy my arg onto the call stack vs construct one there from arg. ie Test( Test (std::move(a))) vs Test(std::move(a)).  To explore more, maybe print inside fun?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each time `fun(Test a)` is invoked, an instance of `Test` is created on the stack. Each time `fun()` returns, the stack frame is freed.

So when invoked twice in a row, the chance is great that you get an instance of `Test` created at exact same location on the stack.

If you wanted to take `Test` by reference, it should be `void fun(Test&& a)`.

Answer (score 2):

> How is it possible ?

The parameters of the separate invocations of `fun` don't have overlapping storage lifetimes. Hence, they can use the same storage.